# parsing through a list in javascript in spring MVC

Tags: javascript, html, list, parsing, spring-mvc

I have the following code in which i have a controller that passes the a variable to a view. In this variable structure is as folows:

```
Structure:
 [sellerId
 sellerDetailsList
      sellerIncentiveDetailList
         {incentiveDetailId,
            },
         {incentiveDetailId
           }
   ]
```

I want to access the incentiveDetailId 
The controller gives this whole structure as "details".
I am able to access the sellerId so uptil there is no problem.

Here is my javascript code :

```
 <c:forEach var="request" items="${details.sellersDetailsList}">
 <script>var i=0;</script>
<table >

    <tr>
        <td> Seller Id</td>
        <td> Incentive id</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${details.sellerId}" /></td>

        <c:forEach  var="a1" items="${request.sellerIncentiveDetailsList}" >
                <td id = "w"> </td>
                <script> 
                document.getElementById("w").innerHTML  =${a1.incentiveDetailId};
                </script>  
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
</table>
</c:forEach>
```

For now I am just focussing on how to retrive the value of the incentiveDetailId and fill all the columns with the same Id .

Comment: Why are writing it _document.getElementById("w").innerHTML       =${a1.incentiveDetailId}_ this way?? It will atlast have only last list objects incentiveDetailId in td with id = w

Comment: Ya for now I am just focussing on getting out the value of incentiveDetailId . Afterward I will make the Id set dynamically. I removed that section of code to make it easier